# How do I enable document map in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the **Sublime text** as well as in **Notepad++** I can enable Document Map.

[Here is a screenshot of the document map of Notepad++.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuW3w.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minimap was added in Visual Studio Code 1.10. The [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap) say:

> To enable VS Code's Minimap, set "editor.minimap.enabled": true to
>   turn on the rendering of a Minimap for the current file.

To set the preference open VS User Settings (Preferences > Settings). This will open two side-by-side documents. Add the entry and set the value to true. In the side-by-side view you choose between changing the "User Settings" (global) or "Workspace Settings" (current workspace only).

```
{
    "typescript.check.tscVersion": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In visual studio 2017 you can simply right click on the scroll bar and click on scroll bar Option. Then on the right panel you can chose to activate the mapping mode on the scroll bar.

I realise this post is about Visual Studio Code and not Visual Studio 2017, but the names are so similar that a lot of people won't know the difference and end up here anyway. To see a post specificaly about Visual Studio 2017, go look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911112/vs-code-minimap-in-actual-vs2017-enterprise).