# VS Code minimap in actual VS2017 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

Does VS2017 (Enterprise, in my case) have a mini-map feature as Visual Studio Code added this year? I looked when the minimap was released for VS Code, thinking the senior Visual Studio editions would have it, but apparently not.

Looked again today, but after an hour of searching on here and Google (as well as looking over the items in Productivity Power Tools 2017) I still can't find barely even a mention of the concept in conjunction with VS2017.

I can see how a mini-map doesn't seem very useful on low-resolution screens (a few things I found were about how other visualization strategies are supposedly better), but with a 4K/5K/8K display, I'd think it would be stellar, as long as you could resize the minimap so that code was legible.

Bottom line - If I want to use an editor with a minimap feature, do I have to downgrade from Enterprise to Visual Studio Code (am I the only one who finds that insane), or is there a plugin or hack I could use?

Comment: VS Code and Visual Studio are entirely different entities. Expecting features to be brought from one to the other is irrational.

Comment: Strikes me as VS Code being a launch point for considering other MS software. A charity product for marketing, largely. Hence rational.

Comment: In visual studio 2017 you can simply right click on the scroll bar and click on scroll bar Option. Then on the right panel you can chose to activate the mapping mode on the scroll bar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio got this minimap already since VS 2015. See the scroll settings where you can switch it on.

Comment: Thanks so much. I must have missed it and will add further commentary if I still have issues.

Comment: To find it: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All languages (Or a language) -> Scroll Bars -> Behavior -> Use map mode for vertical scroll bar

Comment: Difficult to find how to hide it, thanks Tyathalae. Why not right click - hide...

Comment: Right click->Scroll Bar Options